# Avoid sharing bad questions at Facebook

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, facebook, sharing

Related: [Avoid tweeting bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115722/avoid-tweeting-bad-questions)

Sharing questions by [Stack Exchange FB account](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange) is possibly automated, but shouldn't it avoid sharing questions with close votes?

For example [this had](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/84214) (I believe) at least two close votes when [it was shared](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange/posts/794591260582842).

<kbd>[image: FB share screen shot]</kbd>

It is very "helpful" when a question on its way to closure gets 45 likes and 2 shares (many of whom probably have [association bonus to vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773) what they like / share).

I don't know how questions are picked for sharing, but why would we advertise questions that are deemed inappropriate to be "shouted to the twitter universe"?

Comment: I don't think it's automated. More likely SE employee picks hot question he/she deems as excellent and feature it on Facebook. However, I agree they should avoid questions with close votes, regardless of how many upvotes it got.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, it is very "helpful" when a bikeshedding question on its way to closure gets 45 likes and 2 shares (90% of whom likely have [association bonus to vote up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773) what they like / share)

Comment: Yup, that's escalation of the Hot Network Question effect.

Comment: The FB page looks like a joint project of SE and BuzzFeed. Definitely not automatic.

Comment: You use Facebook, @gnat? And I used to think you were cool.

Comment: @Shog9 The screenshot shows gnat either doesn't have an account, or is not logged in. The fact that **SE** uses Facebook is mildly disappointing, though.

Comment: It shows we don't discriminate based on our user's choice of social media service, @raff. No matter how passé. Have you seen our Orkut page?

Comment: @Shog9 you've got to see my _selfies_

Comment: @gnat I +1'd, but I'm second guessing myself. I mean, really , anything we post there will improve the quality of fb. Just think of it as charity work.

Comment: @gnat I thought you were a Java guy.  They're `thisies`.  Selfies are for [php programmers that have some class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/151969/289086).

Comment: They should give us an option to automatically append [cv-pls] while sharing such posts on facebook, it will help. But until they provide [cv-pls], I support your FR.

Comment:  I like this idea.

Comment: @MichaelT don't you know, Java guys can have it too, if device supports _JSR 666 Mobile Selfie API_. API package is `javax.microedition.useless.selfie` - as the name suggests it's the part of MUA, Mobile Useless Architecture, umbrella JSR 678

Comment: Since I couldn't easily find out how to share this QA to Facebook via the UA, I couldn't look this up myself, Does the one who is about to share the QA on Facebook directly see in the interface that there are close votes? Does the interface warn him and ask for confirmation when there are close votes?

Comment: @ChristianHujer if one uses [meta-tag:share-this] button then they can see close votes only if they are over 3K rep or have diamond privileges. If it's shared by an internal software bot, it can "see" everything. It can be a bot (`utm_campaign=programmers-promo`), as link shown in Facebook is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/263589/how-to-break-up-a-programming-project-into-tasks-for-other-developers?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=programmers-promo&utm_source=facebook.com`

Comment: Not the first person to notice this (well, the Twitter bot in this case): http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2629/977

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Stack Exchange Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange) is managed by humans: mostly me, with occasional input from others on the Community Team.

As you noticed, we are not always everyone's favorite DJ. Maybe that's because our Facebook page is mostly top 40, with some self promotion mixed in (blog posts, podcast announcements, site graduations, etc.). Notice, it is the network account, so if you're only into Stack Overflow, you might not be into our Facebook account.

But it's probably true that we should stay away from playing questions with close votes, so we'll be careful about that going forward (and going backward... we deleted the offending post in question).

Thanks for listening. And thanks for keeping us in check.