# Does a tweet indicate HNQ?

Tags: support, hot-questions, twitter

I noticed in the revision history of one of my questions that it said

> Tweeted twitter.com/StackMovies/status/etc.

I also noticed that the question was on the Hot Network Questions and was wondering if the fact that it was tweeted meant that it is one of the HNQ's. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Posts which receive a high number views in a short time period are tweeted by SO's "Hot" algorithm.

Ref: [Nick's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/302377)

Comment: Is this the same "hot" algorithm though? The HNQ algorithm doesn't work on views (see [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page)), only the "hot" tab, which uses [this formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page). It's a little confusing that both of them are called "hot", even though they're very different, and one does not imply the other.

Comment: Not always. The bot also tweets bounty questions on some sites.